# Loading External URL in Angular2 router-outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, router

I am developing an application using Angular2.
I have a component with the following template:

```
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me how to load an external URL 'www.example.com' in this div?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a component to render inside `<ng-outlet>` by using the routing config.
Then you component template inside should have an `<iframe>` pointing to your external site.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-external-page',
    templateUrl: './external-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./external-page.component.css']
})

export class ExternalPageComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'app works!';

    constructor(private _stellarService: StellarService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

}
```

Then your component template should look like

```
<div>
    <iframe src="yourexternalpage url"></iframe>
</div>
```

Having a code like the one above, only remaining step if to configure a route in your routing.

Comment: if the external app have set options to deny rendering in a frame, will this solution work? Also, what risks are posed by opening the app in a frame. If we set the x-frame options to include certain domains, will it help

Answer (score 0):

did you get answer for this ?

You can have a component as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964499/angular2-create-a-component-that-displays-the-content-of-an-external-webpage) . Import and add it to your NgModule; After that import it in the page you want and use the selector instead of `<router-outlet>`.