# Angular2 create a component that displays the content of an external webpage

Tags: iframe, angular

I need to create a component that displays the content of another webpage.

So for instance if I have the site of stackoverflow, I would like to create a component that does a http request and displays the content through my app. By the way, the external website is just django-rest-swagger and to access it, I need to include a header everytime I access it. So, when I make the request for the external site content I need to inlclude the header x-forwarded-host.

```
<div>
     <html> CONTENT OF EXTERNAL WEBSITE </html>
</div>
```

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```ts
@Component({
  selector: ...
  template: `<div [innerHTML]="fetchedHtml"></div>
})
export class ExternalHtml {
  constructor(http:Http) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-forwarded-host', 'foo');
http.get('someUrl', {headers: headers}).subscribe(response => {
    this.fetchedHtml = response.json();
  }
}
```

See also

- [In RC.1 some styles can't be added using binding syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076867/in-rc-1-some-styles-cant-be-added-using-binding-syntax/37076868#37076868)

Alternatively you can also use an iframe to display the fetched HTML.

Comment: can we actually load / embed an external website content inside a component's template on the fly.. ? If so could you explain how we can achieve that.

Comment: Not as easy as many expect but possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular There is a 3rd party project that wraps this in an easy to use component. Sorry, cant remember the name, but saw it mentioned on several andwers to this topic

Comment: Okay. let me check that and try to implement based on my requirement.

Comment: can you guide me on this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243651/custom-modal-dialog-with-dynamic-template-angular-material

Answer (score 0):

You can display it as follows:

```
<div [innerHTML]="contentOfTheExternalWebsite">
</div>
```